# How to define own functions in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

Actually I wanted to know that is there any way to define and call a function in Zend framework which does not need to put with $this like pr() function in cake php. I want to define a such a function which can be called directly in all controllers and views in zend framework. Can it be done by putting all functions in helper and use them without writing $this in front of them.

For example I wanted to make a function arrprint() to print the array in helper and use it globally with only by writing simply arrprint();

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a file anywhere and put the function in there. The just include it like you would any other files.

Or create a library called Utils and put your custom functions there as static and call them using:

```
Utils::myFunction();
```

Contrary to cake zf does not enforce much anything. You can leverage the framework to do whatever you want.

BTW $this is just a pointer to the current class and when you use $this->myFunction(); it's because that function is a member of the current class (or its parent).

Comment: but how to use this function by typing only myFunction();